# Filtering in Kafka and other streaming technologies

Tags: apache-kafka, google-cloud-pubsub

I am currently doing some research about which stream processing technology to use. So far I have looked at message queueing technologies and streaming frameworks. I am now leaning towards Apache Kafka or Google Pub/Sub.

The requirements I have:

- Deliver, read and process messages/events in real time.
- Persistence in the messages/events.
- Ability to filter messages/event in real time with out having to read entire topic. For example: if I have topic called ‘details’, I want to be able to filter out the messages/events out of that topic where an attribute of an event equals a certain value.
- Ability to see if the producer to a certain topic or queue is finished.
- Ability to delete messages/events in a topic based on an attribute within an event equaling a certain value.
- Ordering in messages/events.

My question is: what is the best framework/technology for these use cases? From  what I have read so far, Kafka doesn’t provide that out of the boxes filtering approach for messages/events in topics and Google Pub/Sub does have a filter approach.

Any suggestions and experience would be welcome.

Comment: Queues almost never have consumption filters with any technology. But if you shard/partition correctly, then you don't need to read the entire topic. Plus, if you want persistence, random delete, **and** search functions, you'll want an actual database with indicies. You can use Pinot/Druid/Couchbase _with Kafka_ ingestion

Comment: @OneCricketeer I want to prevent persisting in a database or document store. Currently I have a service that does some actions and stores every line in MongoDB, through which the front-end is updated by ChangeStreams. This is slow as expected, that's why I am considering using a streaming framework like Kafka.

Comment: If you have to update a frontend quicker, you want websockets, not Kafka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the requirements you mentioned kafka seems a nice fit, using kafka streams or KSQL you can perform filtering in real-time, here is an example https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/filter-a-stream-of-events/confluent.html

What you need is more than just integration and data transfer, you need something similar to what is known as ETL tool, here you can find more about ETL and tools in GCP https://cloud.google.com/learn/what-is-etl

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I can basically go either way then; ETL and/or Kafka for these use cases. Will dive into ETL and possibilities there to see how that works, also looking at the scaling abilities. With regard to KSQL in Kafka, that can be done only directly on streams from what I understand, correct?

Comment: In addition to my previous comment and some complimentary notes on my use case: I have a microservice that runs certain processes, which I want to show to output immediately to the front-end (and eventually save). I have been doing this through MongoDB, where I show the results and store line by line accordingly. This is way too slow, therefore I need to stream the output real-time and as soon a process is finished I can store in MongoDB and switch to the stored data.

Comment: Indeed with more detail on the usecase Kafka looks a better choice than etl, and you can create a microservice using kafka or kafkastream apis, both of them works realtime,
you can do filtering in the microservice, example for the same can be seen here with quarkus as the framework but you can find similar with other frameworks https://quarkus.pro/guides/kafka.html